# ClassCastException while trying to call activity from fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have created the Fragment which needs to call to activity which I am referring from developers tutorial. but the following code:

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
{

    super.onAttach(activity);
    try 
    {
        interfaceDataCommunicator = (InterfaceDataCommunicator) activity;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement InterfaceDataCommunicator");
    }

}
```

is throwing classcastexception even I have implemented this interface in mainactivity. I am not able to figure out why. Any help would be heartily appreciated. this is how my mainactivity looks:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements InterfaceDataCommunicator
{
public InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
}


public void updateData(String data)
{
     //interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity.updateData(data);
              this.data=data;
}
```

Comment: add your code from mainactivity and Logcat, it can't be implemented right if it's throwing `ClassCastException`

Comment: What's the stacktrace saying?

Comment: @PontusBacklundI have edited my question

Comment: @ninetwozero stacktrace is showing the error displayed in catch part

Comment: What is the result if you perform `interfaceDataCommunicator = (InterfaceDataCommunicator) getActivity()`in `onCreateView`? Is it the same?

Comment: java.lang.classcastexception if i do that

Comment: @SubodhMankar: Well, my head doesn't have an internal compiler, so I don't really know what to expect of `activity.toString()`... :-)